# syntax error on "if( isnull( if( ..." block

Tags: hana

I am writing a simple SQL having an if block in it. The SQL editor throws syntax error at the if block.

I checked the syntax and it seems to be correct to me. Below is code snippet of the query.

```
select
t4.OWNED,
 if( isnull(
if(t4.OWNED='',
 '01',
 t4.OWNED)),
 '01',
if(t4.OWNED='',
 '01',
 t4.OWNED) ) OWNERSHIP
 from table t4
```

can anyone please suggest if there is issue with the syntax.... thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

your sintax is wrong, i understand you want a result like this

`select t4.OWNED, ifnull(t4.OWNED, '01'), ifnull(t4.OWNED, '01'), ifnull(t4.OWNED, '01') OWNERSHIP from table t4`